# Compare current page number with last page number

Tags: jasper-reports

How do you check to see if the current printed page is actually the last printed page?

I have tried the following:

```
$V{currentPage}.intValue() == $V{totalNumberOfPages} ?
  Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

waited for a long time .. but no reply from Stackoverflow...
Anyway i found my solution..

First in your summary band put this line

```
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.put("LastPageNumber",$V{PAGE_NUMBER}).equals("dummyPrintWhen"))]]></printWhenExpression>
```

Remember this above line must be only in the summary band of the report.

After that you can compare this parameter at any point of time in your report to find last page number .

For Example

```
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean(!$V{PAGE_NUMBER}.equals($P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("LastPageNumber")))]]></printWhenExpression>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate how to do it in design mode?

Comment: can you explain me what you want to do so i can help you .i am always happy if i can help someone.

Comment: Point is: comparation Integer.equals(Integer) will return false if parameter is null. And yes parameter is null (is seted when summary band is processing). So you can put to map Boolean (or any other object) and in condition simple use `$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("isLastPage") IS NULL`

Comment: Mr. Perlos my solutions is working exactly in every condition you can test it practically.

Comment: sarwar026, pretty much the same thing. Take everything between the CDATA[<<contentforDesignMode>>] and place it in the summary band's printWhenExpression property. Ditto any place you want to know if you're on the last page or not. Pretty cool tip, Mihir! Thanks!

Comment: In short you are asking to put last page value in a variable and use it anywhere else... good idea!!

Comment: It is working as long as the summary band does not overflow on more then 1 page, maybe lastPageFooter would be better.

Answer (score 3):

With the following Print When Expression the summary band gets printed again:

```
new Boolean(($P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.put(
"LastPageNumber",$V{PAGE_NUMBER}).equals("dummyPrintWhen")) ||
Boolean.TRUE)
```

You can also use containskey tot test for the existance of the key:

```
new Boolean(!$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.containsKey("LastPageNumber"))
```

Nummeric expressions also work, this expression evaluates to true on every page except the one on which the parameter is set:

```
new Boolean($P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("LastPageNumber") < $V{PAGE_NUMBER})
```

My problem was that I created multiple group footers for several crosstabs at the end of my report, with a constant as the group expression so they get printed only once. By setting the parameter in the first footer I can now finally surpress the column headers without resorting to subreports. Great work!!

Berry.

Comment: Thanks both for your answers, I personally used `$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.put(
"LastPageNumber",$V{PAGE_NUMBER}).equals("dummyPrintWhen") || Boolean.TRUE` for the summary band 'print when' expresion and `$V{PAGE_NUMBER}.equals($P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("LastPageNumber"))` for the field 'print when' expresion

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately your approach didn't worked for me i dont know why.. there are some stuff about your code that are error-prone like this

```
<![CDATA[new Boolean($P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.put("LastPageNumber",$V{PAGE_NUMBER}).equals("dummyPrintWhen"))]]></printWhenExpression>
```

i think in fact that the `Summary Band` is called only once but you have a bad programming practice in this because if there is not key associate with the `KEY in the MAP` it will return null and the you call the method `equals` on it you would receive `NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION` but i think not in this case.

you should reverse like this

```
<![CDATA[new Boolean("dummyPrintWhen".equals($P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.put("LastPageNumber",$V{PAGE_NUMBER})))]]></printWhenExpression>
```

the workaround i used on this question is the following.

1). create a parameter in `jasperreports`

```
parameter name="totalRecordsOnReport" class="java.lang.Integer"
```

2). pass the totals records of your detail as parameter.

```
HashMap<Object,Object>parameters=....
parameters.put("totalRecordsOnReport",yourDetailRowCount);
```

i need to print some stuff only in the last page below the detail and i use this code.

`component print when expression`

```
$V{REPORT_COUNT}.equals($P{totalRecordsOnReport})
```

and prints in the last page.