# How to include "initials" line on all pages except last page when more then one page?

Tags: jasper-reports

In *iReport* I am needing to print some text on all the *page footers* in a document except the last page, but only when there exists more than one page in a document.

The use case is I need people to initial each page of the document and then sign at the end. Things may fit on one page, but it may be 50 pages. I need initial lines on pages 1..49 and then the signature line on page 50.

At first I'd think I could do this with just a straight *PrintWhenExpression*:

```
 new Boolean($V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1 && $V{PAGE_COUNT} > 1)
```

But that does not it appears that those are not evaluated correctly depending on when they are evaluated (now, vs. report vs. page).

Comment: Did you check this post: [Compare current page number with last page number](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5138360/876298)?

Comment: I had not noticed that question. The solution you proposed works great, even though I do find it a bit "Kludgy"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nice solution was described in this post: [Compare current page number with last page number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5138360/876298). I've used it in the sample below.

---

#### Short description

With help of *Summary* page we can set the *flag* that the last page was already drawn.
For initializing this *flag* we can use the *printWhenExpression* of the *Summary* band.

#### The sample

The *jrxml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="last_page_on_page_footer" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="37b03978-a847-40ab-bd19-40bd48de326d">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT TASK FROM TASKS]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="TASK" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="50" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="bec3ccda-ea30-49fa-a0ad-5bb74a2187a5" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TASK}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement uuid="5e4bb895-fd64-4627-bd35-ca1ed71f8dc1" x="455" y="0" width="100" height="20">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.containsKey("LastPageNumber")]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["initials: ___________"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="788fbc43-92cc-4540-abeb-8fa9bf48d25c" x="0" y="0" width="80" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement uuid="95286826-b864-46f8-9922-fc0e2f023ba5" x="80" y="0" width="40" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement uuid="25ccab25-ccd2-4187-8a9b-dff54276042e" x="455" y="0" width="100" height="20">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.containsKey("LastPageNumber")]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Signature: ___   "]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="20">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean(($P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.put(
"LastPageNumber",$V{PAGE_NUMBER}).equals("dummyPrintWhen")) ||
Boolean.TRUE)]]></printWhenExpression>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

The report's design (in *iReport*):

[image]

The result will be. First page (1 of 2):

[image]

And the second (the last page):

[image]

In case only one page the result will be:

[image]

In my sample I've placed one *textField* behind the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the band **"Last page footer"** 
this way you can have one footer for all pages but the last page and a separate one for the last page.

Comment: While this is a good solution that might work for some, we actually have our disclaimer and signature block in a dummy Group footer to push it to the bottom of the page when having just a bit of information. So this doesn't work for us, unless you know of another way to push the page footer to the bottom when the detail doesn't take up much space?