# Print when first page is also last page

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to print something on the detail section only when the report has only one page, but because the PAGE_NUMBER variable has the information but it depends on the evaluation time of the expression, I have no clue how to compare in the same expression the current page and the total number of pages in order to use that in a print when expression. If anyone could help me with that I´ll be really grateful.

Comment: This posts can help you: [How to include “initials” line on all pages except last page when more then one page?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19233673/876298) & [Compare current page number with last page number](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5138360/876298)

Comment: I saw the last one you mentioned but it did'nt work, my summary was gone, so it was not really useful. I did a workaround with the number of elements that should fit in one page and passing that value as a parameter and comparing it in a print when expression, but I don't feel too good with that solution.