# Show last page footer before page footer

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a table of data which is printed over several pages. On each page there is a page footer with symbols that are explained. On the last page I want to show the count of all rows in a last page footer but before the page footer.
Is this even possible? since I can't change the order of the footers...
Or is there another workaround?

Comment: You can determine the last page and use "Page footer" band. You can look at this post: [Compare current page number with last page number](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5138360/876298)

Comment: thanks! this is exactly what I needed

Comment: You are welcome :)