# How to bind footnotes in JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports

I have Textfields with dynamic position. It has footnotes, e.g. "some text<sup>1</sup>". And this footnotes are in the footer.

Footenote must be on the same page with textfield. Textfield has a float position and its location depends from dynamic size of Textfields above. With different conditions the field is located on different pages

How to bind TextField whith footnote in one page, e.g. Textfield is on the page number 3 and footnote on the same page? I can use $V{PAGE_NUMBER}, but how to get current page of TextField?

Comment: `PAGE_NUMBER - Built-in variable containing the current page number.` Your question is unclear

Comment: Footenote must be on the same page with textfield. Textfield has a float position and its location depends from dynamic size of Textfields above. With different conditions the field is located on different pages

Comment: You can play with map parameters and hidden fields to hide/show footnote. The main idea of trick described here: [Compare current page number with last page number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5138360/876298)

Comment: Thanx! That helped

Answer (score 2):

I have added `$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.put("id_1",$V{PAGE_NUMBER}))` at the end of textFiled Expression and `$V{PAGE_NUMBER}.equals($P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("id_1"))` in the *PrintWhenExpression* of textField in the footer

Comment: Hi, this helped me A LOT. Thank you so much for this.

Comment: how exactly can you declare this `$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.put("id_1",$V{PAGE_NUMBER})` at the end of textField expression? I've tried multiple options, but neither of them works

Answer (score 1):

@mdenci You can do it in Text Field Expression by this way
`$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.put("id_1",$V{PAGE_NUMBER}) == null ? "some text1" : ""`