# How to make a counter on Page footer?

Tags: jasper-reports

Some components on my Report should only appear at specific pages, but since I can't use PAGE_NUMBER inside "print when expression", because of evaluation time, I was trying to create a counter variable at page footer that counts pages, tried a lot of solutions from the internet, but with no success, anyone have a hint?

iReport version = 4.5.0

Comment: You can try the trick with storing page number at map (from the dupe link)

Comment: I've tried those dupe links, no success... But found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138360/compare-current-page-number-with-last-page-number/5151824

Comment: @AlexK could put this link on the dupe link? This could be usefull for someone