# Jasper report - compare page_number and page_count

Tags: jasper-reports

How can we check the condition to compare the current page with a total no of the page in the `Jasper` report?
I tried the following ways but no luck.

```
1. new Boolean(!$V{PAGE_NUMBER}.equals($V{PAGE_COUNT}) 
2. $P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("isLastPage") == null
```

I am having two-footer, first one should print in all the pages and the second one should print on the last page only.

no luck.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare current page number with last page number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138360/compare-current-page-number-with-last-page-number)

Comment: no, this is make disappear even in other pages also.

Comment: When it comes to footers only, actually there is a special band "last page footer" - just use that. If you want to do something different in some other band on the last page then that answer from the duplicate is your only option.